# 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.' when attempting to advance to new line from CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv

I'm a QA tester who is new to python, trying to create a script to create multiple XML files from a CSV file containing various fields. I feel I am close to creating this program. Unfortunately,I have been getting the following error when adding code to advance to the next line in the CSV file(line = next(reader)).If I don't add the line to to advance, the program will run but multiple xml files will be created with information from only the first line of the CSV file. I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\defxmlImportcsv.py", line 22, in <module>
    line = next(reader)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Here is my code:

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import csv

```
with open('datanames.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    x=0 
    line = next(reader)
    line = next(reader)
while x<2:
    filename = "Output"+str(x)+".xml"
    [firstName,lastName] = line
    print(line)
    tree = etree.parse('WB5655(BR-09).xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    registration_id=tree.find('primaryApplicant/ssn')
    registration_id.text = str(53)
    first_name = tree.find('primaryApplicant/firstName')
    first_name.text = (line[0])
    last_name = tree.find('primaryApplicant/lastName')
    last_name.text =(line[1])    
    line = next(reader)
    tree.write(filename)
    print(x)
    x=x+1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csvfile` is automatically closed when you exit your `with` block. Which means that `reader`, in turn, can no longer read from it, causing your `line = next(reader)` line to fail.

The easiest (and likely most correct) fix is to add indentation to your code so that your `while` loop is *inside* the `with` block.

Comment: Thank for the help, the files are now created. I am still getting an error message, but I think it's due to the code reading the last 'line = next(reader)' statement. I think I may have to put a break in there somewhere. Here is the error.... :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\defxmlImportcsv.py", line 29, in <module>
    line = next(reader)
StopIteration

Comment: Indeed, iterators raise StopIteration when you call `next()` on them after they're exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

You exited the `with` statement:

```
with open('datanames.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    x=0 
    line = next(reader)
    line = next(reader)
while x<2:
     # ...
```

The moment the `while` line is reached the `csvfile` file object is *closed*, because, logically, that block is *outside* of the `with` statement (not matching the indentation).

The solution is to indent the whole `while` loop to be within the `with` block:

```
with open('datanames.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    x=0 
    line = next(reader)
    line = next(reader)
    while x<2:
         # ...
```

Rather than use `while`, use `itertools.islice()` to loop just twice:

```
from itertools import islice

tree = etree.parse('WB5655(BR-09).xml')
registration_id=tree.find('primaryApplicant/ssn')
registration_id.text = '53'

with open('datanames.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # skip two lines
    next(islice(reader, 2, 2), None)

    for x, row in enumerate(islice(reader, 2)):
        filename = "Output{}.xml".format(x)
        first_name = tree.find('primaryApplicant/firstName')
        last_name = tree.find('primaryApplicant/lastName')
        first_name.text, last_name.text = row
        tree.write(filename)
```

I simplified your XML handling as well; you don't have to read the input XML tree twice, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately, when running this code I get the following error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\defxmlImportcsv.py", line 14, in <module>
    next(islice(reader, 2, 2))
StopIteration

Comment: @DwaynePindling: your file appears to be empty. I've silenced that exception, but the code now will not do anything.

Comment: @DwaynePindling: but for reference: the `StopIteration` means there are not enough lines in the file to iterate 2 times.